# Origin of the circle in ぬ, ね, and る

Tags: history, hiragana

When looking at the hiragana ぬ (*nu*), ね (*ne*), and る (*ru*) one notices a small circle in the symbols. In fact that circle is the only difference when comparing them with the hiragana め (*me*), れ (*re*)　and ろ (*ro*).

In the history of hiragana, is there any special reason that lead to this. And while I could see the relation of ね/れ and る/ろ (given that they sound similar), why are ぬ and め so different in their pronunciation?

[image: “Mahoraba” by Kojima Akira]

(Image was taken, and slightly adjusted, from the manga “Mahoraba” by Kojima Akira)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They all originate from the cursive versions of kanji with the same/similar pronunciation as the hiragana. Here's a picture [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#History) to illustrate:

[image: origin of the hiragana]

To answer your question - there is no deep connection between the kana with circles. The kanji they came from just happened to have a circle when written in cursive.

And just to be complete, Wikipedia also has a picture on [the origin of katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana#History). They're a bit more obvious because they're taken from the "plain" forms of the kanji.

Comment: Interestingly enough, in the case of め and ぬ, ぬ derives from a kanji with the left radical the same as the origin of め.